# User or the user?

Tags: definite-article

In [another post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59527/a-phrase-for-describing-the-reaction-of-an-element-to-an-action) I wrote this sentence

> In our software we ask user to specify ....

Other suggested (by editing) to use "the user", I thought I mean user in general and not a specific user, so I used it without "the"

Why "the user"?

Some of my interpretations:

I don't refer to a specific user, but maybe it gets "the" to distinguish it from users of applications in general! I mean "the user of our software", it gets "the" because we said "our software" before it. Could it be a valid interpretation?

For another interpretation we may imagine that surrounding a software there are many group of people, managers, developers, testers.... but we mean users, "the user" not "the developer"!

Comment: It depends. If you have already 'defined' the user, it takes 'the'. If it's a very first line of yours, it takes 'a'. Without any article, it'd look ungrammatical to some, including me! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

> The user

To refer to your users as individuals in the sense of

> We asked the user to specify

You are talking about each user which is more personal than

> Users

Where as an example you might say

> We try to simulate how users find their desired data

Where you talk about your users in a general way.

In order to decide between the two, have a  look at the Documentation for a few web apps that you use, and see what the preferred style is.

In short, the rule is as follows:

"The + singular noun" when referring to a specific user like in your examples.

"Plural noun" (without an article) when speaking in general about all  users.

Comment: I don't refer to a specific user, but maybe it gets "the" to distinguish it from users of any application! I mean "the user of our software", it gets "the" because we said "our software" before it. Could it be a valid interpretation? for another interpretation we may imagine that surrounding a software there are many group of people, managers, developers, testers.... but we mean users, "the user" not "the developer"